# Can't scrape multiple pages in a website after the first using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to web scraping and programming in general.  I was trying to make a program that could scrape all of the reviews for a movie off Rotten Tomatoes and put them into a pandas dataframe I could manipulate later.  Currently my program can successfully scrape the first page of reviews but won't click next and continue scraping from there.  For what it is worth the url does not change when you move through the pages of reviews.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Setting up Chrome options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Path to chromedriver
webdriver_service = Service(r"C:\Users\Brend\Videos\chromedriver_win32")

# Create instance of Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/thor_love_and_thunder/reviews"

driver.get(url)

data = []

while True:

    # Scrape the reviews on the current page
    reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-row')
    for review in reviews:
        critic_name = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.display-name').text.strip()
        publication = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.publication').text.strip()
        review_quote = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.review-text').text.strip()
        review_date = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-qa="review-date"]').text.strip()
        score_icon = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'score-icon-critic')
        state = score_icon.get_attribute('state') if score_icon else None

        #Take data and put into pandas dataframe
        review_data = {
            "Critic Name": critic_name,
            "Publication": publication,
            "Tomato Quality": state,
            "Review Quote": review_quote,
            "Review Date": review_date
        }

        data.append(review_data)

    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'rt-button.next')))
    next_button.click()
    # Delay for a few seconds before continuing to the next page
    time.sleep(2)

    # Check if we have reached the last page
    current_url = driver.current_url
    if current_url == url:
        # We are back to the first page, exit the loop
        break

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('reviews_data.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lame answer but it should solve your problem. Your problem is so easy to solve, I don't believe it that you failed to recognize it.

Because you really did write all the code yourself, and the code isn't half-bad, in fact it is quite good for a beginner. But I was skeptical that you wrote all it, after all if you wrote all of it surely you will immediately know what is wrong?

I put your code comments in the textbox in https://writer.com/ai-content-detector/ to check if it is generated by ChatGPT. It says: "97% HUMAN-GENERATED CONTENT; Fantastic!"

Now, your problem.

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'rt-button.next')))
```

You correctly found the next button, but you never actually clicked it.

Just add this line below it:

```
next_button.click()
```

Or, since you didn't use it again anywhere after in your code, you don't need to assign a named variable. Just click it immediately after it is found:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'rt-button.next'))).click()
```

With all that said, to make this answer less lame, I found one problem in your code.

```
critic_name = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.display-name').text.strip()
publication = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.publication').text.strip()
review_quote = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.review-text').text.strip()
review_date = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-qa="review-date"]').text.strip()
```

The above four lines are essentially the same, it is exactly the same syntax, same functions, the only difference is that the string part is different. Since you already know to use `for` loops, why not put the strings in a `tuple` and iterate through it?

Or, even better, since you are creating a dictionary using these variables, use a dictionary comprehension instead, you can loop using multiple variables, like so:

```
for a, b in [('zero', 0), ('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)]:
    print(a, b)
```

Also, `By.CSS_SELECTOR` is `'css selector'`, you can just use the string directly, in this way you don't need to import `By` and the code is more concise, but this is a matter of styling choice.

So you can create `review_data` like the following:

```
review_data = {
    key: review.find_element("css selector", css).text.strip()
    for key, css in [
        ("Critic Name", "a.display-name"),
        ("Publication", "a.publication"),
        ("Review Quote", "p.review-text"),
        ("Review Date", 'span[data-qa="review-date"]'),
    ]
}
```

That being said, score can't be processed using the same syntax. But the above method reduces code repetition. You need to just add it later using dictionary assignment.

But first, the following lines don't do what you think they would do:

```
score_icon = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic")
state = score_icon.get_attribute("state") if score_icon else None
```

You are finding an element and check for its existence. You can't use its truth value to tell if an element was found. If the element wasn't found, selenium raises `NoSuchElementException` and stops code execution instead of making the element falsy.

So you have to catch the exception using try-except.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    state = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic").get_attribute("state")
except NoSuchElementException:
    state = None

review_data["Tomato Quality"] = state
```

And you haven't used `Options` in your code. I recommend you to delete that line, or don't use `selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions`, `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options` is preferred over `selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions`, the latter is deprecated.

Also use the following lines to get rid of the annoying debug messages:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

---

And no, if you click the next button the url never changes, so your condition `url == current_url` is always `True`, you will never get all the reviews, since the `while` loop will break on the first iteration...

I am patient enough to click the next button enough times, and I have discovered that when the end is reached, the next button is hidden. So we can keep clicking until the next button is hidden.

Your CSS selector `'rt-button.next'` will always find the element, even when it is hidden, when the button is hidden its class is `"next hide"`, so using the XPATH `'//rt-button[@class="next"]'` will not find the element when it is hidden and raise `NoSuchElementException`, so we can catch it and break the loop when it is raised.

```
try:
    wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath", '//rt-button[@class="next"]'))
    ).click()
except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    break
```

Full code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Setting up Chrome options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")


# Path to chromedriver
webdriver_service = Service(r"C:\Users\Brend\Videos\chromedriver_win32")

# Create instance of Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/thor_love_and_thunder/reviews")
data = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    # Scrape the reviews on the current page
    reviews = driver.find_elements("css selector", "div.review-row")
    for review in reviews:
        review_data = {
            key: review.find_element("css selector", css).text.strip()
            for key, css in [
                ("Critic Name", "a.display-name"),
                ("Publication", "a.publication"),
                ("Review Quote", "p.review-text"),
                ("Review Date", 'span[data-qa="review-date"]'),
            ]
        }
        try:
            state = review.find_element("css selector", "score-icon-critic").get_attribute("state")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            state = None

        review_data["Tomato Quality"] = state

        data.append(review_data)

    try:
        wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath", '//rt-button[@class="next"]'))
        ).click()
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        break

    # Delay for a few seconds before continuing to the next page
    time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("reviews_data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

---

### ***Edit***

Some adjustments according to [JeffC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc)'s comments.

For the first point, dictionary comprehension doesn't make things simpler, I disagree. When you have a large amount of data, for example when you read data from disk or receive data over the internet, your method won't work, you have to do comprehension, one way or another.

But here indeed using comprehension is making things a little more complicated for such few keys.

For the second point, `By.CSS_SELECTOR` is the standard, yes, it is. So what? I have always hated authorities, norms, rules, standards, traditions, and whatnot... But since this isn't my code, I don't care if you want to follow the standard or not, it is your choice.

Now, taking account into the above two points, your original code indeed does have a lot of repetition. We can write a function to wrap up the reused code to reduce repetition and increase reusability:

```
def get_text(node, css):
    return node.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css).text.strip()
```

Use like this, suppose you have a variable named `review` that is an element of `reviews`, and you want the text of the subelement located using the CSS selector `"a.display-name"`, use the following syntax: `get_text(review, "a.display-name")`.

With the above function we can construct `review_data` in this way:

```
review_data = {
    "Critic Name": get_text(review, "a.display-name"),
    "Publication": get_text(review, "a.publication"),
    "Review Quote": get_text(review, "p.review-text"),
    "Review Date": get_text(review, 'span[data-qa="review-date"]')
}
```

Point three, yes, I was aware of `driver.find_elements` syntax, and I know it returns an empty `list` if no elements were found, it is indeed the preferred way to check for element existence. I was trying to teach the original poster the syntax of try-except.

So we can find the element by using `find_elements`, and check if the `list` is empty, if the `list` is empty, we assign `state` to `None`, else we get the first element by indexing, then get the `'state'` attribute, like the following code:

```
state = review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic")
if state:
    state = state[0].get_attribute("state")
else:
    state = None
```

Using the walrus operator we can assign and check in the same line, like so:

```
if state := review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic"):
    state = state[0].get_attribute("state")
else:
    state = None
```

Using ternary expression we can compress the above code in one line:

```
state = state[0].get_attribute("state") if (state := review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic")) else None
```

With the above changes we can construct `review_data` this way:

```
review_data = {
    "Critic Name": get_text(review, "a.display-name"),
    "Publication": get_text(review, "a.publication"),
    "Review Quote": get_text(review, "p.review-text"),
    "Review Date": get_text(review, 'span[data-qa="review-date"]'),
    "Tomato Quality": state[0].get_attribute("state") if (state := review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic")) else None
}
```

At this point there is no need to assign a named variable, since it isn't referenced afterwards and is immediately appended to the `data` `list`, we can just inline the structure to `data.append` call.

Point four:

> You should always prefer CSS selectors over XPaths. CSS selectors are faster, simpler syntax, better supported on browsers, and so on.

Yes, CSS selector is simpler and faster, but XPATH is more powerful. Actually I have never learned CSS selector syntax, I always used XPATH. With my knowledge and intelligence it isn't actually hard for me to learn CSS selector syntax, I just never saw the point and never took the time to learn it. But maybe new programmers should learn it.

I also discovered that `wait.until` seems to raise `TimeoutException` for elements that weren't found,  and never `NoSuchElementException`, so we can check the `break` condition like so:

```
try:
    wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'rt-button.next:not(.hide)'))
    ).click()
except TimeoutException:
    break
```

Finally yes, I know I don't need to pass driver executable and I never did it, but I did put the folder the executable is located at into my `PATH` environment variable, I have never tested if it will work if no executable path was passed and the executable isn't present in `PATH`. You should add the executable to `PATH` variable, too.

With all the adjustments, the code becomes:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/thor_love_and_thunder/reviews")
data = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)


def get_text(node, css):
    return node.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css).text.strip()


while True:
    reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.review-row")
    for review in reviews:
        data.append(
            {
                "Critic Name": get_text(review, "a.display-name"),
                "Publication": get_text(review, "a.publication"),
                "Review Quote": get_text(review, "p.review-text"),
                "Review Date": get_text(review, 'span[data-qa="review-date"]'),
                "Tomato Quality": state[0].get_attribute("state")
                if (state := review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-icon-critic"))
                else None,
            }
        )

    try:
        wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "rt-button.next:not(.hide)"))
        ).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break

    time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("reviews_data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: You made several good points but I disagree with a few: 1. Looping through and using dictionary comprehension doesn't make things simpler. You took 4 lines that were easy to read and turned it into 9 that are less easy to read and reuse. 2. Using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` is the standard, see [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). Yes, "css selector" is what it resolves to but then you have to worry about spelling, capitalization, typos, etc. in a string where with a modern IDE you can easily type `By.CSS`... and autocomplete it.

Comment: 3. A better method to test for element existence is to use `review.find_elementS(...)` (plural) and then test for list contents.

Comment: 4. You should always prefer CSS selectors over XPaths. CSS selectors are faster, simpler syntax, better supported on browsers, and so on. I'm not saying XPaths don't have a place... they are the only locators that can be used to find text contained in an element and to do complicated DOM traversal. XPaths that do exact string matches, e.g. `//rt-button[@class="next"]` are particularly brittle because if *any* other class is added to that element, that locator will fail. Using a CSS selector, `rt-button.next:not(.hide)` will not break on changes to the class and still find the desired button.

Comment: I know this isn't your code but you no longer need to specify the path to the driver as of Selenium 4.6. Selenium Manager takes care of that for you... see [this](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager).